# Yii2 AdminLTE: how to load left.php file?

Tags: php, view, menu, yii2, adminlte

I am using [yiisoft/yii2-app-basic](https://packagist.org/packages/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic) with [dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset](https://packagist.org/packages/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset) but I can't load the left.php file (it has the left menu).

I want to change the left menu (left.php file) and I found this in the [AdminLte documentation](https://packagist.org/packages/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset):

> **Customization**
>
> - (1) Copy files from vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app (or
>   other theme) to @app/views.
> - (2) Remove the custom view configuration from your application by deleting the path mappings, if you have made them before.
> - (3) Edit your views adhering to html markup vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/pages

So I copied all files from `vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app` to `My Project/views` (item 1):

[image: My project folders]

But I don't understand item 2 and item 3.

The file `My Project/views/site/index.php is` loaded but my file `My Project/views/layouts/left.php` is not loaded. Instead the file `vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app/layouts/left.php` is loaded.

How can I load my left.php file?

This is my siteController `actionIndex()` function:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

Comment: show please how you render it

Comment: Check your main.php inside config folder. Inside composer-> view you have to modify the path for the view.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I don't have a main.php config file. I only have a main.php file in views/layouts/.

Comment: You can refer to the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Check the web.php file inside config folder, find the next code:

```
'view' => [
     'theme' => [
         'pathMap' => [
            '@app/views' => '@vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app'
         ]
     ]
 ]
```

After find it, you can delete or change to

```
'pathMap' => ['@app/views'],
```